# porting .net we apps to VS2017 on mac

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio

I am developing .net applications on a mac using parallels where I have a windows VM and all my .net tooling.

now that visual studio 2017 can run on mac, would i be able to eliminate my method and run visual studio direct on my mac and seamlessly be able to move my code over to the mac version and compile and develop asp.net web applications?

I am only worried about web applications.

Comment: I think you should port the projects to .NET core, because classic .NET cannot run on mac.

Comment: core is horrible, lose a lot of functionality.

Comment: .net core is still in deep developing, but will be the future.
Other alternatives are, use of mono instead .NET  or remote compiling on windows.

Comment: VS2017 does not run macOS. Visual Studio for Mac is not quite VS yet. Besides, "seamless" is almost impossible. Try it and you learn from the problems.